# Contract income by year - depend on contract length

Tags: powerbi, dax

First of all, I don't have much experience with Power BI and DAX.

I have question about calculating yearly income depend contract length and showing company year by year income.

Data is stored in Excel file and all contracts have information about contract_start (datetime), contract_end (datetime) and annual contract value (income).

So for example:

I have 5 contracts (A, B, C, D, E):

- A - end year 2019 (worth 1M/per year €)
- B - end year 2019 (worth 1M/per year €)
- C - end year 2020 (worth 2M/per year €)
- D - end year 2021 (worth 1M/per year €)
- E - end year 2022 (worth 5M/per year €)

So my end result must be (sum of annual contract income per year):

[image]

- 2019 = A+B+C+D+E
- 2020 = C+D+E
- 2021 = D+E
- 2022 = E

Edit:
Additional: It's possible to also include contracts, which have blank **contract_end**? If contract has blank **contract_end** it means that contract is valid until cancelation.

So I have beside contract A, B, C, D, E also 2 contract, F and G which have "blank" contract_end and each it's worth 1M/year.

- A - end year 2019 (worth 1M/per year €)
- B - end year 2019 (worth 1M/per year €)
- C - end year 2020 (worth 2M/per year €)
- D - end year 2021 (worth 1M/per year €)
- E - end year 2022 (worth 5M/per year €)
- F - until cancelation (worth 1M/per year €)
- G - until cancelation (worth 1M/per year €)

It's possible to add "virtual" 2M€ to each year in chart (sum of F and G)?

Example in image:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your table looks something like this:

[image]

then a maesure like this:

```
Total_Income =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'table'[Yearly_Income] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'table' ),
        'table'[EndYear] >= SELECTEDVALUE ( 'table'[EndYear] )
    )
)
```

results in a Column chart like this ('table'[Endyear] on Axis and [Total_Income] on Value):

[image]